# Target only final row of floated divs, via css

Tags: css

I have rows of 4 divs, floated. The way it works is that each div is 25% width so there will always be 4 divs per row. There is no container div around each row.

I wonder if there is a way, via CSS, to target ONLY the divs on the final row, no matter if there are 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 divs there (it will vary as the site is dynamic).

I thought maybe with nth-child values there might be a way but I can't get my head around it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  counter-reset: div
}

div {
  counter-increment: div
}

div:before {
  content: counter(div)
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

#test div:nth-last-child(5)~div:nth-child(4n)~div {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<section id="test">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</section>
```

You can combine nth-child and nth-last-child :

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QqNvLV

```css
div:nth-last-child(5) ~ div:nth-child(4n) ~ div {
  background:gray;
}
```

---

To go further to include to include cases where there is less than 6 boxes, a few pseudo class need to be combined.

:pseudoclass can also be used to play with other style.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
div:nth-child(3n) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}

div:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2em rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.1)
}

.test div:nth-last-child(6)~div:nth-child(4n)~div,
.test div:nth-last-child(5):first-child~div:nth-child(4n)~div,
.test div:nth-last-child(4):first-child,
.test div:nth-last-child(4):first-child~div,
.test div:nth-last-child(3):first-child,
.test div:nth-last-child(3):first-child~div,
.test div:nth-last-child(2):first-child,
.test div:nth-last-child(2):first-child~div,
.test div:nth-last-child(4):first-child,
.test div:last-child:first-child {
  background: gray;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px, 1px -1px, 1px 0;
  border: none;
}

.test {
  counter-reset: div;
  width: 8em;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.test:nth-child(2n)
{
  float:none;
  display:inline-table;
}
.test:nth-child(3n)
{
  float:right;
  /*clear:left;*/
}
div {
  counter-increment: div
}

div:before {
  content: counter(div)
}
```

```html
<section class="test"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></section>
<section class="test"><div></div><div></div><div></div></section>
<section class="test"><div></div><div></div></section>
<section class="test"><div></div></section>
<section class="test"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></section>
<section class="test"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></section>
<section class="test"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></section>
<section class="test"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></section>
<section class="test"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></section>
<section class="test"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></section>
```

Comment: Great answer! I think it would be much better to change the codepen link to inline snippet :)

Comment: Thanks so much! This works in all cases except:

1) Where there are 4 divs on the last row, and
2) Where there are 4 or less divs total

Comment: @siaeva i have updated answer with a second snippet to show more combined pseudoclass when items are less than 6. pen updated too https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QqNvLV

Comment: @G-Cyr you are a genius! This worked perfectly :) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

(updated) You can use CSS `:last-child` selector. Example:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}
  
.col {
  width: 25%;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}

div.row:last-of-type div.col {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
  </div>
```

Another way to do it, without container, using both `:last-of-type` and `:last-child`:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  width: 25%;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}

div.row:last-of-type div.col:last-child {
  background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It seems I keep getting the question wrong, to select only the divs of the last row:

```
div.row:last-of-type div {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but there are no container divs around each row as you have it in your html (and I don't want to add any so that I can easily format it differently as required).

Comment: `:last-child` is the only option if there isn't more structure.

Comment: The OP wrote "There is no container div around each row"

Comment: My bad, I updated adding a solution without need of a container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there are going to be at least 12 and at most 16 elements and there are going to be 4 per row, you can use a pseudo selector `nth-child(n+13)`:

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
margin:0;

}


  
.col {
  width: 25%;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.col:nth-child(n+13) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
    <div class="col">7</div>
    <div class="col">8</div>
    <div class="col">9</div>
    <div class="col">10</div>
    <div class="col">11</div>
    <div class="col">12</div>
    <div class="col">13</div>
    <div class="col">14</div>
    <div class="col">15</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! unfortunately I need a solution that works for any number of elements.